# How do I pivot in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which I am trying to Pivot. I am partially able to achieve what I want. I need help in completing it

**My base table**

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| WorkOrderID | STEP_NBR | STEP_STATUS |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
| AA100       |        0 | C           |
| AA100       |        1 | W           |
| AA100       |        2 | W           |
| AA200       |        0 | W           |
| AA200       |        1 | W           |
| AA300       |        0 | C           |
| AA300       |        1 | C           |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

**My Desired Output**

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| WorkOrderID | Step_0 | Step_1 | Step_2 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AA100       | C      | W      | W      |
| AA200       | W      | W      |        |
| AA300       | C      | C      |        |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Output I am getting**

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| WorkOrderID | Step_0 | Step_1 | Step_2 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AA100       | C      | null   | null   |
| AA100       | null   | W      | null   |
| AA100       | null   | null   | W      |
| AA200       | W      | null   | null   |
| AA200       | null   | W      | null   |
| AA300       | C      | null   | null   |
| AA300       | null   | C      | null   |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

My Query

```
SELECT WorkOrderID, 
(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 0 THEN STEP_STATUS ELSE NULL END) AS Step_0,
(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 1 THEN STEP_STATUS ELSE NULL END) AS Step_1,
(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 2 THEN STEP_STATUS ELSE NULL END) AS Step_2
FROM Table1
```

How do I get rid of multiple WorkOrderId. I just want 1 row for each WorkOrderId

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czvQmj1vya6VsA4ApPDAmE/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need aggregation:

```
SELECT WorkOrderID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 0 THEN STEP_STATUS END) AS Step_0,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 1 THEN STEP_STATUS END) AS Step_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP_NBR = 2 THEN STEP_STATUS END) AS Step_2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY WorkOrderID;
```

`ELSE NULL` is redundant, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain how does `MAX` in this case works

Comment: The `GROUP BY` produces one row per `WorkOrderId`.  The `MAX()` is choosing one value that matches each condition.